# Can Transaction across machine with JMS?

Tags: distributed-transactions, spring-jms

Case:
Start: create transaction

1. Insert Data to DB (Machine A)
2. send sync JMS message to Queue (Machine A)
3. receive JMS message from the Queue (Machine B)
4. Insert Data to DB and return (Machine B)
5. further process in (Machine A)

End: Commit transaction

Can the process in Machine A and B working with one transaction. Therefore, process A rollback if the process B rollback and vice versa ?

Is there any example? Any extra server/component are needed?

Answer (score 0):

you will need some sort of transaction server, I'd suggest to use [JOTM](http://jotm.ow2.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome)

Comment: I am new to JMS. It is JMS must be async call. Therefore, transaction in machine A will be committed after sent the message to JMS queue ?

Comment: no, the data will be committed after you successfully finish your transaction on step 4.

Comment: If i am using JBoss7, it is necessary to use JOTM ?